# Accessing custom element's child element without using slots & shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, chromium, custom-element

I have an input element nested inside my custom element and I want to tamper the input element from my custom element. I don't want to use shadow DOM and slots to do it.

[Example in Codepen](https://codepen.io/jutunen/pen/BaaJPVE)

[Example in Github](https://github.com/jutunen/custom-element-experiment)

```
connectedCallback () {
  const template = document.createElement("template");
  template.innerHTML = templateDiv;
  this.appendChild(template.content);

  console.log(this.querySelector('input'))
  console.log(this.firstElementChild)
}
```

Everything works OK on Firefox. But on Chromium, I can not access the child element from the custom element. When querying for the input element with *this.querySelector*, I just get null on Chromium.

Could this be considered as a bug in Chromium or is it just that Firefox does more than it should?

Comment: The `<slot>` element would solve your problem. Could you explain why you don't want to use it?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I would have to introduce shadow DOM in to my code. I'd like to keep things as simple as as possible...

Comment: Yes that is true. There is a "hacky" way to do it, but I would still encourage you to use the Shadow DOM as it does what you want in a really great way. But that depends on you.

Comment: where you get ``null`` and expect a value... wrap your console.logs inside a ``setTimeout( func , 0)`` to delay execution till new nodes are really ready in the DOM. Long explanation is about Chromium/V8 and Event Loops I only half understand. Layman's answer is: your 5 codelines in the same scope are somehow optimized by the browser engine and the DOM nodes are only created after those 5 lines executed. ``setTimeout`` makes sure code executes after the eventloop has finished.. or something like that..It is not specifically Custom Elements related

Comment: Thank you @Danny'365CSI'Engelman for your insight, I did a quick test, and you're right! I wonder whether I now have to try to build some fancy asynchronous handling for getting the child element.

Comment: Nothing fancy, ``setTimeout`` is enough. I use it in many ``connectedCallbacks``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman you're right, again. There is not much official documentation for setTimeout with zero delay. But I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Comment: Good deep-dive video at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ keyphrase: *"it can't do a render if there is code on the stack"*